# Changing to fixed positioning when scroll position is at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I am checking to see if the scroll position is at the bottom of the page and adding and remove a class based on that. However when removing the fixed class I can't scroll to the bottom of the page. The browser already assumes I am at the bottom. How can I correct this? If this doesn't make sense please let me know. Below is my code:

**JavaScript :**

```
function fixedToRelative(){
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if(scrollPos == $(document).height()) {
        $('.mobile.full').removeClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.mobile.full').addClass('fixed');
    }
}
```

**Css :**

```
.mobile { position:relative; }
.mobile.fixed { position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; }
```

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is ... also how did you trigger the function ? on scroll?

Comment: Please add more relevant code

Comment: So currently I am checking scroll position on scroll. If you see the example I have posted above, it shows that there is space to still scroll at the bottom of the page. After I added relative positioning it does this. It will not let me scroll any further. The way I am doing things, I beleive it acts like the window is already scrolled to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to append add the `.fixed` class when you scroll to the bottom of the page. If so, you could do something like:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWVvxd)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height(); // Current Scroll position plus height of window
    var atBottom = (scrollPos == $(document).height()); // Returns true/false based on if at bottom
    $('.mobile').toggleClass('fixed', atBottom); // If at bottom of page, fixed class is appended
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Do you mind explaining where I was going wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you have your add/remove class stuff reversed. Other than that, it should work. But I also am not sure how you are running the `fixedToRelative()` function since you don't show that. Something could be an issue there.